# MySQL: Select records where joined table matches ALL values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to find all employees with multiple skills. Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
INSERT INTO `Employee` (`ID`, `Name`, `Region_ID`) VALUES (1, 'Fred Flintstone'), (2, 'Barney Rubble');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Skill` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
INSERT INTO `Skill` (`ID`, `Name`) VALUES (1, 'PHP'), (2, 'JQuery');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Emp_Skills` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Emp_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Skill_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
INSERT INTO `Emp_Skills` (`ID`, `Emp_ID`, `Skill_ID`) VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1);
```

Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(em.ID), em.Name 
FROM Employee em 
INNER JOIN Emp_Skills es ON es.Emp_ID = em.ID
WHERE es.Skill_ID IN ('1', '2')
```

This returns both employees, however, I need to find the employee that has both skills (ID 1 and 2).

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ make life easy in this case

Comment: is this you want ? 
SELECT DISTINCT(em.ID), em.Name ,skill.Name
FROM employee em 
INNER JOIN emp_Skills es ON es.emp_ID = em.ID
LEFT JOIN skill ON skill.id= es.skill_id
WHERE es.skill_ID IN ('1', '2')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT EmpId, Name
FROM
(
   SELECT em.ID as EmpId, em.Name, es.ID as SkillID 
   FROM Employee em 
   INNER JOIN Emp_Skills es ON es.Emp_ID = em.ID
   WHERE es.Skill_ID IN ('1', '2')
 ) X
GROUP BY EmpID, Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SkillID) = 2;
```

[Fiddle here:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ad68/7)

The distinct is just in case the same employee has the skill listed twice.

Thanks for the test data.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, that did the trick. I have never used nested queries before.

Comment: I love stack's suggested post feature...I had the exact same questions and this did the trick!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT em.ID, em.Name 
FROM Employee em INNER JOIN
     Emp_Skills es
     ON es.Emp_ID = em.ID
GROUP BY em.id, em.name
HAVING sum(es.Skill_id = '1') > 0 and
       sum(es.Skill_id = '2') > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows for each employee that have a particular skill.  The filter guarantees that both skills are present.