# MySQL: Select all records where it matches multiple IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is based on a question that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619480/mysql-select-records-where-joined-table-matches-all-values/21619564#21619564).

I need to export relational records to a flat CSV file. It displays a list of employees that match two skills. The export needs to have a separate line for each skill. For example:

```
EMPID  NAME               SKILLNAME  LEVEL
1      Fred Flintstone    PHP        Basic
1      Fred Flintstone    JQuery     Advanced
3      Steve Jobs         PHP        Basic
3      Steve Jobs         JQuery     Advanced
```

Here's the tables/records and a modified version of the previous answer: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35fe1)

I have tried a few variations but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: I had a related problem which has already been answered. The code I am working with is a modified version of that.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I've tried removing the GROUP BY which gave me no results. Just using the nested query - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35fe1/32 - gives all records, even if the employee does not have both skills.

Answer (score 1):

You need a sub query to find the employees that have more than 2 skills. And then you just list the details of those skills by joining it to the Emp_skills table.

```
SELECT Emp_SKills.*
FROM Emp_Skills
JOIN (
SELECT COUNT(*) as skills, Emp_ID
FROM Emp_Skills
GROUP BY Emp_ID
HAVING skills > 1
) as mult ON mult.Emp_ID = Emp_Skills.Emp_ID
ORDER BY Emp_SKills.Emp_ID
```

Comment: The number of skills would change each time it is used. It could be 1 or 20.

Comment: IF you only want employees that have exactly 2 skills then change "HAVING > 1" into "HAVING = 2".  If you want to only report on 2 skills then you can join with a MAX() id and a MIN() or some other arbitrary set of 2.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I was actually searching for employees with all the selected skills. Fabio has point me in the right direction and I was able to work it our from there. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There you go with a subquery

```
SELECT a.Emp_ID, b.Name, c.Name as skname, a.Level
FROM Emp_Skills a
LEFT JOIN Employee b
ON a.Emp_ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN Skill c
ON a.Skill_ID = c.ID
WHERE ( 
       SELECT count(d.Emp_Id) as total 
       FROM Emp_Skills d
       WHERE d.Emp_id = a.Emp_id 
       GROUP BY Emp_id
      ) > 1
ORDER BY a.Emp_ID ASC
```

Sql fiddle [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35fe1/31)

Based on op new info

```
SELECT a.Emp_ID, b.Name, c.Name as skname, a.Level
FROM Emp_Skills a
LEFT JOIN Employee b
ON a.Emp_ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN Skill c
ON a.Skill_ID = c.ID
WHERE ( 
       SELECT count(d.Emp_Id) as total 
       FROM Emp_Skills d
       WHERE d.Emp_id = a.Emp_id 
       GROUP BY Emp_id
      ) > 1
AND a.Skill_ID IN ('1', '2')
ORDER BY a.Emp_ID ASC
```

New sql fiddle [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35fe1/33)

Comment: Thanks. I need to specify the ID of the skills. In the live db, I have over 100 skills and you can search for employees with a select number of skills. The number of skills changes for each search.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show an example? So i can fix this for you

Comment: Sorry, the query does not show up in SQL Fiddle. Here it is: SELECT EmpId, Name, SkillName, Level
FROM
(
   SELECT em.ID as EmpId, em.Name, es.Level as Level, sk.Name as SkillName, es.ID as SkillID 
   FROM Employee em 
   INNER JOIN Emp_Skills es ON es.Emp_ID = em.ID
   INNER JOIN Skill sk ON sk.ID = es.Skill_ID
   WHERE es.Skill_ID IN ('1', '2')
 ) X
GROUP BY EmpID, Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SkillID) = 2;

Comment: Thanks for your help Fabio. I was able to work out the solution based on your answer. See below…

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.emp_id, b.name, c.name as skname, a.level
  from emp_skills a
  join employee b
    on a.emp_id = b.id
  join skill c
    on a.skill_id = c.id
 where b.id in (select emp_id from emp_skills where skill_id = '1')
   and b.id in (select emp_id from emp_skills where skill_id = '2')
   and a.skill_id in ('1', '2')
```

**SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35fe1/40/0 **

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fabio, I was able to find the solution based on his answer. The final query is:

```
SELECT a.Emp_ID, b.Name, c.Name as skname, a.Level
FROM Emp_Skills a
LEFT JOIN Employee b
ON a.Emp_ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN Skill c
ON a.Skill_ID = c.ID
WHERE ( 
       SELECT count(d.Emp_Id) as total 
       FROM Emp_Skills d
       WHERE d.Emp_id = a.Emp_id 
       GROUP BY Emp_id 
       AND d.Skill_ID IN ('1', '2')
      ) = 2
AND a.Skill_ID IN ('1', '2')
ORDER BY a.Emp_ID ASC
```

I have added

```
AND d.Skill_ID IN ('1', '2')
```

so it only finds employees with the selected skills. I am not concerned with the skills I am searching for, not the total number of skills an employee has. I have also changed '> 1' to '= 2'. That will change with the number of skills being search for. So if I am looking for an employee with 4 particular skills, it would be '= 4'.

Thanks everyone.