# Nested JOIN to locate records with multiple WHERE criteria in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[Using this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619480/mysql-select-records-where-joined-table-matches-all-values), I learned how to nest a query but I'm finding that the WHERE statement is ignored?

I want to return only EmpID that have the 4 QualID specified found in the Quantifications tables.  It appears this returns EmpID where any of these values match the EmpID.

**Employee Table:**
EmpID, EmpName

**Qualifications Table:**
EmpID, QualID

```
SELECT EmpID, QualID
FROM
(
   SELECT Employee.EmpID as EmpID, HTG_TechQual.QualID as QualID 
   FROM Employee Employee 
   INNER JOIN Qualifications Qualifications ON Qualifications.EmpID = Employee.EmpID
   WHERE Qualifications.QualID IN ('3', '34', '35', '37')
 ) X
GROUP BY EmpID DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause to select only those groups having all 4 `QualID`s

```
SELECT e.EmpID
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN Qualifications q ON q.EmpID = e.EmpID
WHERE q.QualID IN ('3', '34', '35', '37')
GROUP BY e.EmpID
HAVING count(distinct q.QualID) = 4
```