# Symfony Doctrine Many-To-Many filter results with QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have two tables:

Users

Groups

One user can have many groups and one group can have many users.

I am trying to build a query where I have an array of groups and I want to find all users who belong to ALL the groups in array and print all the groups of each of those users. For example:

Table Users:

User 1 - belongs to groups 1,2,3

User 2 - belongs to groups 2,3,4,5

User 3 - belongs to groups 3,4

User 4 - belongs to groups 4,5

Table Groups:

Group 1

Group 2

Group 3

Group 4

If I have an array [Group 3, Group 4], I'd like to filter my tables and get:
User 2 - Groups 2,3,4,5
User 3 - Groups 3,4

No matter what I try (using 'MEMBER OF', 'IN', etc.), I will always get all the users that have at least one of the groups (e.g. User 1 from my example which has Group 3 but not Group 4).
Here's a relevant part of my code:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->leftJoin('u.groups', 'g')
            ->where(':groups MEMBER OF u.groups')
            ->setParameter('groups', $groupsArray);
```

When I use "IN" instead of "MEMBER OF", the only difference is that I will get the same results but only groups from the Array will be in the data set (e.g. User 2 will have groups 3 and 4 instead of all of the ones from the example).

EDIT (answer to Destroy666):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT(g.id)) as total_groups')
->leftJoin('u.groups', 'g') ->where('g.id IN (:groups)')
->setParameter('groups', $groupsArray) ->groupBy(u.id)
->andHaving('total_groups = ' . count($groupsArray));
```

This works but it doesn't fetch all the groups the user belongs to. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use a simple query like that, use something more complex like any of these 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619480/mysql-select-records-where-joined-table-matches-all-values

Comment: ~~~
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT(g.id)) as total_groups')
            ->leftJoin('u.groups', 'g')
            ->where('g.id IN (:groups)')
            ->setParameter('groups', $groupsArray)
            ->groupBy(u.id)
            ->andHaving('total_groups = ' . count($groupsArray)); 
~~~

This works but it doesn't fetch all the groups the user belongs to. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's better to not post code in the comments but to edit your question and build on the examples you have given there.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fetch"? Show how you're trying to access the groups.